# Which amount of code execution should I parallelize?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, parallel-processing

If I want to parallelize the execution of an algorithm what are the smalls chunks of code that I should split?

A classic example is a sorting algorithm. For what element size or typical execution time does it make sense to split the sorting between multiple threads? Or when is the overhead for waiting on another thread larger than the execution time on a single thread?

Are there any simple rules? Does this depend on the OS?

Comment: Tough question to answer - really depends on the problem domain and the hardware constraints i.e sort - how many items are you sorting and on what hardware

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key rule is "fork only when the forking overhead is much smaller than the amount of work the fork will do".   Since forking overhead is a property of the specific technology you use, and so is the effort to do the work, you in some sense have to determine this empirically.  You'll likely end up with some threshold tuning constant in your code to represent this tradeoff.

What you will discover in practice is that finding seperable chunks of work is actually hard. If you make the work chunk small, it hasn't got a lot of dependencies and you can schedule it once all its input dataflows are ready.  But small chunks usually mean small work, and the forking overhead usually negates the gain.   If you try to make the chunks big, they have so many dependences that you can't break them out to schedule them.

Some people are lucky and can find such big chunks; we call most of those people physicists and/or Fortran programmers and they are taking advantage of data parallelism induced by dividing the world into as many tiny pieces as they can.

The only decent cure I know of is to use a spectacularly fast forking mechanism, so that you can find the smallest practical chunks.   Unfortunately, the parallelism libraries offered to do this are ... libraries, invoked dynamically, with corresponding dynamic invocation overhead.  Typical libraries containing parallelism primitives takes 100s to thousands of cycles to implement a "fork"; this is bad news if your chunk of work is 100 machine instructions.

I believe strongly that to get such fast forking mechanisms, the language compiler has to know that you are doing the fork, e.g., "fork" (however spelled :-) has be a keyword in the language.  Then the compiler can see the forks, and preallocate everything needed to minimize the time to accomplish this, and generate special code to manage the forking (and joining) steps.

The [PARLANSE](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/Parlanse/index.html) language that I designed, and that we use at Semantic Designs is one such language.
It is a Lisp-like language in syntax (but not in semantics). Its parallelism operator is spelled  "(|| ... )".  You can see it below in the Quicksort module we use daily, below.
You can also see the explicit QuickSortParallelThreshold value, determined empirically.
This Quicksort scales linearly to 8 cores on an Intel x86 system.

```
(define QuickSort
  (module
    (;; (define Value nu)
        (compileifthen (~ (defined QuickSortWithParlanseBuiltInOrderingOfNu))
          (define QuickSortWithParlanseBuiltInOrderingOfNu ~f) ; use PARLANSE comparison operators
        )compileifthen
        (compileifthen (~ (defined QuickSortParallelThreshold))
          (define QuickSortParallelThreshold 100)
        )compileifthen
        (compileifthen (~ (defined QuickSortThreshold))
          (compileifthenelse QuickSortWithParlanseBuiltInOrderingOfNu
            (define QuickSortThreshold 16)
            (define QuickSortThreshold 8)
          )compileifthenelse
        )compileifthen
        (compileifthenelse (~ (defined QuickSortWithCompareByReference))
          (define QuickSortWithCompareByReference ~f)
          (compileifthen QuickSortWithParlanseBuiltInOrderingOfNu
            (define QuickSortWithCompareByReference ~f)
          )compileifthen
        )compileifthenelse
        (define SortRange
          (action (procedure (structure (compileifthen (~ QuickSortWithParlanseBuiltInOrderingOfNu)
                                          (compileifthenelse (~ QuickSortWithCompareByReference)
                                            [compare (function (sort integer (range -1 +1)) (structure [value1 Value] [value2 Value]))]
                                            [compare (function (sort integer (range -1 +1)) (structure [value1 (reference Value)] [value2 (reference Value)]))]
                                          )compileifthenelse
                                        )compileifthen
                                        [a (reference (array Value 1 dynamic))]
                                        [from natural]
                                        [to natural]
                             )structure
                  )procedure
            (local (;; (define quicksort
                         (action (procedure (structure [l integer] [r integer])))
                       )define

                       (define quicksort
                         (action (procedure (structure [l integer] [r integer]))
                           (ifthenelse (<= (- r l) (coerce integer QuickSortThreshold))
                             (do [i integer] (++ l) r +1
                               (local (= [exch Value] a:i)
                                 (block exit_if_inserted
                                   (;; (do [j integer] (-- i) l -1
                                         (ifthenelse (compileifthenelse QuickSortWithParlanseBuiltInOrderingOfNu
                                                       (> a:j exch)
                                                       (compileifthenelse (~ QuickSortWithCompareByReference)
                                                         (== (compare a:j exch) +1)
                                                         (== (compare (. a:j) (. exch)) +1)
                                                       )compileifthenelse
                                                     )compileifthenelse
                                           (= a:(++ j) a:j)
                                           (;; (= a:(++ j) exch)
                                               (exitblock exit_if_inserted)
                                           );;
                                         )ifthenelse
                                       )do
                                       (= a:l exch)
                                   );;
                                 )block
                               )local
                             )do
                             (local (;; (= [i integer] l)
                                        (= [j integer] r)
                                        (= [p integer] l)
                                        (= [q integer] r)
                                        [exch Value]
                                    );;
                               (;;
                                  `use middle element as pivot':
                                    (local (= [m integer] (// (+ l r) +2))
                                      (;; (= exch a:m)
                                          (= a:m a:r)
                                          (= a:r exch)
                                      );;
                                    )local
                                  `4-way partitioning = < > =':
                                    (loop exit_if_partitioned
                                      (;;
                                         `find element greater than pivot':
                                           (loop exit_if_greater_than_found
                                             (;; (compileifthenelse QuickSortWithParlanseBuiltInOrderingOfNu
                                                   (ifthenelse (< a:i a:r)
                                                     (consume ~t)
                                                     (ifthenelse (> a:i a:r)
                                                       (exitblock exit_if_greater_than_found)
                                                       (;; (ifthen (>= i j)
                                                             (exitblock exit_if_partitioned)
                                                           )ifthen
                                                           (= exch a:p)
                                                           (= a:p a:i)
                                                           (= a:i exch)
                                                           (+= p 1)
                                                       );;
                                                     )ifthenelse
                                                   )ifthenelse
                                                   (case (compileifthenelse (~ QuickSortWithCompareByReference)
                                                           (compare a:i a:r)
                                                           (compare (. a:i) (. a:r))
                                                         )compileifthenelse
                                                     -1
                                                       (consume ~t)
                                                     +1
                                                       (exitblock exit_if_greater_than_found)
                                                     else (;; (ifthen (>= i j)
                                                                (exitblock exit_if_partitioned)
                                                              )ifthen
                                                              (= exch a:p)
                                                              (= a:p a:i)
                                                              (= a:i exch)
                                                              (+= p 1)
                                                          );;
                                                   )case
                                                 )compileifthenelse
                                                 (+= i 1)
                                             );;
                                           )loop
                                         `find element less than to pivot':
                                           (loop exit_if_less_than_found
                                             (;; (-= j 1)
                                                 (ifthen (>= i j)
                                                   (exitblock exit_if_partitioned)
                                                 )ifthen
                                                 (compileifthenelse QuickSortWithParlanseBuiltInOrderingOfNu
                                                   (ifthenelse (< a:j a:r)
                                                     (exitblock exit_if_less_than_found)
                                                     (ifthenelse (> a:j a:r)
                                                       (consume ~t)
                                                       (;; (-= q 1)
                                                           (= exch a:j)
                                                           (= a:j a:q)
                                                           (= a:q exch)
                                                       );;
                                                     )ifthenelse
                                                   )ifthenelse
                                                   (case (compileifthenelse (~ QuickSortWithCompareByReference)
                                                           (compare a:j a:r)
                                                           (compare (. a:j) (. a:r))
                                                         )compileifthenelse
                                                     -1
                                                       (exitblock exit_if_less_than_found)
                                                     +1
                                                       (consume ~t)
                                                     else (;; (-= q 1)
                                                              (= exch a:j)
                                                              (= a:j a:q)
                                                              (= a:q exch)
                                                          );;
                                                   )case
                                                 )compileifthenelse
                                             );;
                                           )loop
                                         `move found elements to proper partitions':
                                           (;; (= exch a:i)
                                               (= a:i a:j)
                                               (= a:j exch)
                                           );;
                                         `increment index':
                                           (+= i 1)
                                      );;
                                    )loop
                                  `3-way partitioning < = >':
                                    (;;
                                       `move pivot to final location':
                                         (;; (= exch a:i)
                                             (= a:i a:r)
                                             (= a:r exch)
                                             (= j (-- i))
                                             (= i (++ i))
                                         );;
                                       `move elements equal to pivot to final locations':
                                         (;; (do [k integer] l (-- p) +1
                                               (;; (= exch a:k)
                                                   (= a:k a:j)
                                                   (= a:j exch)
                                                   (-= j 1)
                                               );;
                                             )do
                                             (do [k integer] (-- r) q -1
                                               (;; (= exch a:i)
                                                   (= a:i a:k)
                                                   (= a:k exch)
                                                   (+= i 1)
                                               );;
                                             )do
                                         );;
                                    );;
                                  `sort partitions not equal to pivot':
                                    (ifthenelse (<= (- r l) (coerce integer QuickSortParallelThreshold))
                                      (;; (quicksort l j)
                                          (quicksort i r)
                                      );;
                                      (|| (quicksort l j)
                                          (quicksort i r)
                                      )||
                                    )ifthenelse
                               );;
                             )local
                           )ifthenelse
                         )action
                       )define

                   );;
              (;; (quicksort (coerce integer from) (coerce integer to))
                  (ifdebug (do [i integer] (coerce integer from) (-- (coerce integer to)) +1
                             (trust (compileifthenelse QuickSortWithParlanseBuiltInOrderingOfNu
                                      (<= a:i a:(++ i))
                                      (compileifthenelse (~ QuickSortWithCompareByReference)
                                        (<= (compare a:i a:(++ i)) +0)
                                        (<= (compare (. a:i) (. a:(++ i))) +0)
                                      )compileifthenelse
                                    )compileifthenelse
                                    `QuickSort:Sort -> The array is not sorted.'
                             )trust
                           )do
                  )ifdebug
              );;
            )local
          )action
        )define

        (define Sort
          (action (procedure (structure (compileifthen (~ QuickSortWithParlanseBuiltInOrderingOfNu)
                                          (compileifthenelse (~ QuickSortWithCompareByReference)
                                            [compare (function (sort integer (range -1 +1)) (structure [value1 Value] [value2 Value]))]
                                            [compare (function (sort integer (range -1 +1)) (structure [value1 (reference Value)] [value2 (reference Value)]))]
                                          )compileifthenelse
                                        )compileifthen
                                        [a (reference (array Value 1 dynamic))]
                             )structure
                  )procedure
            (compileifthenelse (~ QuickSortWithParlanseBuiltInOrderingOfNu)
              (SortRange compare a (coerce natural (lowerbound (@ a) 1)) (coerce natural (upperbound (@ a) 1)))
              (SortRange a (coerce natural (lowerbound (@ a) 1)) (coerce natural (upperbound (@ a) 1)))
            )compileifthenelse
          )action
        )define

    );;
  )module
)define
```

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the overhead of the inter-thread communication. I tested openMP with image processing, and there a line of pixels was convenient, as well giving good speedups. My image was a megapixel, so there were 1000 tasks, which is probably more than enough to keep today's manycore machines busy. You also don't need to limit yourself to jobs that take more than a second or so. In this example the speedups of jobs of the order of 10 milliseconds where clearly visible.

Now this was a pleasant algorithm because it was not recursive, so there were no dependencies of one task on the other, and all the tasks were automatically the same size.

Sorting algorithms will be harder, due to varying task sizes. You'd want to be able to experiment with this, and maybe choose a sort that is easier to paralellize.

Answer (score 1):

Take couple of courses in concurrent and parallel programming. Learn several technologies like plain old fork & forget or "manual" multithreading (Java threads or pthreads), MPI, OpenMP, BSP, maybe even CUDA or OpenCL. Then either decide to be an expert or let the experts design and implement efficient and correct parallel algorithms. The "parallel" part is easy, the "efficient" and "correct" parts are not, when both are needed. Even Java concurrent Vector collection, designed and implemented by experts, was not free from bugs in the first versions. The mere definition of memory model was not clear in the first versions of Java standard!

The simplest rule: **use ready-to-use components *designed and implemented by experts*** and don't try to achieve both correctness and efficiency designing your own parallel algorithms unless you're an expert.

Answer (score 1):

Solving this problem programmatically is one of the holy grails of parallel computing, and there are many libraries that can approximate the optimal parallelism for particular problems (e.g., Data Parallel Haskell).

Anyhow, to do this by hand, you need to understand:

- The algorithm that you wish to parallelize (Is it parallelizable?)
- The characteristics of the data, e.g., sizes, location (on disk, in memory), etc.
- The hardware that you're running on, e.g., number cores, memory latency, cache sizes/lines/associavity, etc.
- The threading model of both the implementation language (coroutines, green threads, OS threads) and OS.
- Cost of spawning and context-switching between threads.

Assuming that the algorithm is parallelizable, your goal is to find the number of threads and the relative chunk size of the data, such that you can make optimal use of the hardware to generate a solution.

This is quite hard to do without lots of experimentation. My preferred way of figuring this out is by running lots of benchmarks, and getting performance data as a function of one or more combinations of the following:

- Number of threads.
- Buffer sizes (if the data is not in RAM) incrementing at some reasonable value (e.g., block size, packet size, cache size, etc.)
- Varying chunk sizes (if you can process the data incrementally).
- Various tuning knobs for the OS or language runtime.
- Pinning threads to CPUs to improve locality.
- Etc.

Anyhow, this is no easy task, and there are tools and libraries to help you squeeze as much performance as is possible out of your parallelizable problems. The only reasonable way you can do this correctly by having a good understanding of your data, your code, and your runtime environment.